# nl80211 not found

Tags: kernel, wifi, drivers

#### Environment

- Linux 3.0.8 compiled for ARM
- FriendlyARM mini210s

I cross-compiled `iw` for an ARM board (friendlyARM mini210s), when I installed the utility and ran it, I got this message:

```
# iw --help
nl80211 not found.
```

Where do I get `nl80211` driver and how do I install it?

### Complementary information

```
#  wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf  
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
Failed to initialize driver 'nl80211'
```

... whereas the following works (note that the `-Dwext` to use the `wext` driver instead):

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Doe [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?&t=18745) help?

Comment: It is a similar problem indeed, but they do not point to a resolution. I believe this is a driver to include when compiling the kernel ... yet I am not sure, and so far I don't know how to do that.

Comment: They did include a workaround, which was NOT to use `iw` and try `iwconfig`, so does that work?

Comment: `iwconfig` works fine but it always did. My problem is really to have `iw` finding `nl80211` driver. BTW `wpa_supplicant` also takes that driver by default and complains about not finding it too, instead it works using the `wext` driver. I am curious about how to add this driver to my config, if that is possible

Comment: You don't get it, the post I referred to is a bug.  If it works using iwconfig, the driver exists properly in the kernel.  If it was a driver issue, both commands would complain.  As such, you can use `iwconfig` until the bug is fixed, and if there are no bugs regarding this, you need to report one

Comment: So you are saying this is an `iw` bug right?

Comment: Yes, or a kernel bug.  Just file one and the maintainers will move the bug to the proper category.

Comment: See my question update.

Comment: See [another blog post](http://www.mrjansen.com/Raspberry-Pi/configuring-hostapd-on-raspberry-pi.html)